# troubleshooting referring to dictionary (python)

Tags: python, dictionary

this code is supposed to recreate minesweeper - it takes a list of (equal length) lists of values true and false(representitive of the grid and true where there are mines), and is supposed to return an array ('grid') with a number in each spot representing the amount of bombs ('true's) next to it.

this code seems to be right (I still need to turn the dictionary back into a grid) but i can't figure out how to correctly change each dictionary entry in respect to it's [lace in the grid. also my code is way long and repetitive. why isn't this working and how can I make it more concise? thanks!:

```
def minesweeper(m):
    r = len(m)          # this is the len of num of lists
    c = len(m[0])
    new1 = dict()
    ans = []
    for i in range(r):
        row=[]
        for j in range(c):
        #    print(m[i][j]) 
            new1[i,j] = 0
        for j in range(c):
            if m[i][j] == True:
                print('fine')
                if i == 0:#if it is the 'top' list
                    if j == 0:#top left
                        new1[i+1,j]+=1
                        new1[i+1,j+1]+=1
                        new1[i,j+1]+=1

                    elif j == c-1:#top right
                        new1[i,j-1]+=1
                        new1[i+1,j]+=1
                        new1[i+1,j-1]+=1
                    else:#top mid
                        new1[i,j-1]+=1
                        new1[i+1,j-1]+=1
                        new1[i+1,j]+=1
                        new1[i+1,j+1]+=1
                        new1[i,j+1]+=1

                elif i == r-1: #if it is the 'bottom' list
                    if j == 0:#bot left
                        new1[i-1,j]+=1
                        new1[i-1,j+1]+=1
                        new1[i,j+1]+=1

                    elif j == c-1:#bot right
                        new1[i,j-1]+=1
                        new1[i-1,j]+=1
                        new1[i-1,j-1]+=1
                    else:#bot mid
                        new1[i,j-1]+=1
                        new1[i-1,j-1]+=1
                        new1[i-1,j]+=1
                        new1[i-1,j+1]+=1
                        new1[i,j+1]+=1

                else: #one of the middle lists
                    if j == 0:#mid left
                        new1[i,j+1]+=1
                        new1[i+1,j+1]+=1
                        new1[i-1,j+1]+=1
                        new1[i-1,j]+=1
                        new1[i+1,j]+=1
                    elif j == c-1:#mid right
                        new1[i,j-1]+=1
                        new1[i+1,j-1]+=1
                        new1[i-1,j-1]+=1
                        new1[i-1,j]+=1
                        new1[i+1,j]+=1
                    else:
                        new1[i,j-1]+=1
                        new1[i-1,j-1]+=1
                        new1[i-1,j]+=1
                        new1[i-1,j+1]+=1
                        new1[i,j+1]+=1
                        new1[i+1,j+1]+=1
                        new1[i+1,j]+=1
                        new1[i+1,j-1]+=1
        
    print(new1)

minesweeper([[True,False,False],
 [False,True,False],
 [False,False,False]])
```

here is the error I got:
keyError: (1,0)

[image: this is the full error:]

Comment: The error is simply that when you are working on row `i`, you have not yet created row `i+1` in the dict, so `new1[i+1, j]` does not yet exist.

Comment: Also, if the cell _is_ a bomb, what should it return?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference you may want to be more specific, or include an error message.

Dictionaries are not 2D by nature. Each piece of data in the dictionary can be needs only one piece of data. You need to create a dictionary or a list for each row of data.

```
## The Data structures you want should look like this:
##   Dict in Dict                    List in Dict             List in List
##   { 1: {1: a, 2: b, 3: c},        { 1: [a, b, c]           [[a, b, c],
##     2: {1: d, 2: e, 3: f},          2: [e, f, g]            [e, f, g],   
##     3: {1: g, 2: h, 3: i}}          3: [h, i, j] }          [h, i, j]]
```

Also, you may want to iterate i and j over [-1, 0, 1], creating exceptions for if you're on the edge.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I was trying to use the dict values to keep track of each item I wanted to edit, and what I wanted it's value to be. there was supposed to be a corresponding dict item for every item in the list(not for each sublist, but for each item in every sublist). I'll add the error to the OP maybe that will help clarify. or maybe I'm just not understanding your answer. thanks anyways!

Comment: @EnderBromson
My bad! I'll clarify. Python dictionaries are not two dimensional.
In other words, this is valid:
mydict[1]
This is invalid:
mydict[1, 2].

Grids cannot be stored in a dictionary. Only a line. rcriii's default dict may get around that for you. Lmk if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

[defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is the solution to your error. Then you can use miguel's idea to shorten your code significantly.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def minesweeper(m):
    r = len(m)          # rows and columns
    c = len(m[0])

    #Turn the map into a defaultdict to handle edge cases
    #Note that the int function returns 0
    map_dict = defaultdict(int, [((i, j), m[i][j]) for i in range(r) for j in range(c)])
    
    new1 = defaultdict(int) #new keys start with a value of 0
    for i in range(r):
        for j in range(c): #Iterate on the rows and column
            for x in [-1, 0, 1]:
                for y in [-1, 0, 1]:
                    new1[i,j] += map_dict[i+x, j+y]
            
        
    print(new1)



minesweeper([[True , False, False],
             [False, True , False],
             [False, False, False]])
```

`defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {(0, 0): 2, (0, 1): 2, (0, 2): 1, (1, 0): 2, (1, 1): 2, (1, 2): 1, (2, 0): 1, (2, 1): 1, (2, 2): 1})`